# Is it possible to quantify the tendency for electrons to move between two spatial points for a region with magnetic field present?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

It is clear that a potential function can not be defined in presence of magnetic field and faraday's law only gives the expression for EMF over closed loops. Such a thing as EMF between two point is nonsense. I figure that this means it would be impossible to quantify the tendency like we do in regular case with no magnetic field using potential, would I be correct? If not, describe a scheme to quantify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the case of a circular path around the middle of a long solenoid, and co-axial with a it. Let us call four equally spaced points around the circular path: N, E, S, W. The solenoid has a current through it that is rising at a constant rate, so the emf around the circular path is constant (with value $\mathscr E$, in the sense NESW, say.)

We can surely say that there is an emf, $\frac {\mathscr E}4$ in the short arc, NE, and of $\frac {3\mathscr E}4$ in the long arc ESWN. So we can talk about the emf *along specific paths* between N and E, but not about just "the emf between N and E".

Comment: Since there are multipile paths with different EMF, which path does the electron take? Is it the path which coincides with the physical loop?

Comment: Even when there is a conservative field due to static charges, predicting paths of charged particles isn't straightforward. The path of a free charge isn't usually along a field line through its initial point if the line is curved. This because of what might  loosely be called 'centrifugal effects'. And in the case of the circular loop around the solenoid, I think that the electron would *not* follow it. My answer above is very narrow: I don't think you can deduce very much of any use from it! Sorry not to be more helpful.